# Implement autocomplete using custom analyzers in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Referring to [this post](https://qbox.io/blog/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams), I've created the following mapping:

```
POST music
{
  "song": {
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "nGram_filter": {
            "type": "nGram",
            "min_gram": 2,
            "max_gram": 20,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit",
              "punctuation",
              "symbol"
            ]
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "nGram_filter"
              ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "song_field_1": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inserted the following document:

```
POST music/song
{
  "song_field_1" : "Premeditiated fella"
}
```

And sent this query:

```
POST music/song/_search
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "_all": {
            "query": "pre"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I expected to get the document as an autocomplete option, but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your index like this:

```
POST music
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "nGram_filter": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "nGram_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "nGram_filter"
            ]
          },
          "whitespace_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "song": {
      "properties": {
        "song_field_1": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So:

1. `song` goes inside `mappings`
2. No need for `"index": "not_analyzed"` since you're specifying analyzers

Comment: thanks man.
Can you explain further why song needs to go inside mappings ?
Why putting song outside mapping and settings doesn't give me parsing exception ?

Comment: `song` is the mapping type you're defining, hence it needs to go inside the `mappings` section. [An index can be defined](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings) by the two top-level sections (among others) `settings` and `mappings`. Agreed that the query should fail, though.